# Sonicwall Global VPN not working

Tags: vpn

I was using SonicWall Global VPN for a long time and it was working perfectly. But I am having trouble in connecting it for last few days. I have tried the following, but nothing helped.

1. Uninstalled Hamachi VPN
2. Uninstalled and re-installed SonicWall
3. Turned-off firewall.
4. Turned off anti-viruses

But it is working fine in my friend's machine, it is working fine.

Not sure what is the problem with my machine.

Can anyone suggest any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes sonic VPN is not working because ISAKMP packet sent option is not enable. We need to mark it restrict first packets.

steps:
 1. Go to File menu
 2. Select properties
 3. Click to Restrict the size of the first ISAKMP packet sent.

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting while connecting ? If it's stuck in connecting , it would be the `OS` version and `GVC` versions are not compatible !

```
Windows 7 : GVC version 4.7
Windows 8 and above : 4.9.9
```